# Pattern Matching Types in C# Language Ext

Tags: c#, functional-programming, pattern-matching

I'm using pattern matching in C# to walk an rtf DOM-like parse tree and think this seems to be a neat way to be able to handle different subnodes of the overall RTF DOM. e.g.

```
RTFDOM
  RTFDOMText
  RTFDOMParagraph
  RTFDOMTable
    RTFDOMRow
      RTFDOMCell
      RTFDOMCell
  RTFDOMParagraph
  etc ...
```

Using .Net 4 and have been using Matthew Podwysocki's version which provides the following style for pattern matching on types ...

```
var result = RTFDOM.Elements
                   .Aggregate(..., 
                              (seed, el) =>
                              { 
                                 var r = el.Match()
                                           .With<RTFDOMText>(st1 => ...)
                                           .With<RTFDOMTable>(st2 => ...)
                                           .Default(_ => ...)
                                          .Return<MyNewType>()
                                 ...
                              });
```

I've just come across [this](https://github.com/louthy/language-ext) nuget-based c# language extension offering a slightly more extensive FP offering. But I'm not sure if you can pattern match on type using it.

If anyone has used this language extension, how would I achieve this? Having said that, if there is a better way to think about the problem, I'm happy to consider something different.

Comment: Language.ext does, in fact, support pattern matching, but IIRC only on those types it provides (such as Option, Either, etc.).

Comment: thx vm meiston!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

language-ext author here :)

The problem with any pattern matching framework in C# is that it can't do completeness checking and is usually very clunky.  For this reason I decided not to implement a generalised system.  The approach I use in my own projects is to use the ternary operator and C# 7's built in pattern matching:

```
var result = el is RTFDOMText text   ? UseTheText(text)
           : el is RTFDOMTable table ? UseTheTable(table)
           : HandleDefault(el);
```

It involves some manual formatting, but is quite attractive and minimal.  It doesn't do completeness checking but forces you to provide a default.

Comment: I introduced language-ext to a previous project and, even without pattern matching a la F# or Haskell, it made the code much more readable and maintainable.  Great library!

Comment: Thanks melston, that's great to hear :)

Comment: Consider updating your response here to take the new `switch expression`s into account.